# Alt Tab window won't disappear after releasing alt key (with AutoHotKey script)

Tags: autohotkey

My apple wireless key board is connected to a Windows 10 computer. I switched the left alt key and left Win(command) key (<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>) with AutoHotKey script:

```
#NoTrayIcon
RAlt::Delete ; right-Option to context menu
RWin::AppsKey ; right command to forward delete

LWin::LAlt ; left command to alt
LAlt::LWin ; left alt to command (windows key)

CapsLock::ESC
```

The problem is when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↹Tab</kbd> to switch between windows, the switch dialog won't exit after <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↹Tab</kbd> are released. Annoying! So I tried the following solution:

```
LWin & Tab::
IfWinExist ahk_class #32771
{
    GetKeyState, StateWin, LWin, P
    If StateWin = U
        WinClose, ahk_class #32771
}
```

the #32771 is the ahk_class of switch window. The switch window never showed up again. I'm not familiar with AutoHotKey scripting , anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Briefly had this exact problem, though with normal PC and keyboard.

Pressing "WinKey + Tab" for the alternate, and virtual desktop interface fixed the issue without having to perform a restart.